# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' ( on Mac OS )

Tags: python, pandas, macos, jupyter-notebook, pip

I get this error when importing pandas in jupyter notebook. But I've install Pandas with the brew command and it was successful. I also installed Pandas with the pipx command of the terminal, but I still encounter the same error when importing it. In addition that my mac os terminal doesn't accept the pip command.

Comment: If you want to get past this hurdle without connecting what you already installed. In other words, you don't mind adding yet another version of Pandas on your system as long as it gets it working in Jupyter, then you want to do what AKX says. In a new cell in the notebook where you want to import Pandas, run `%pip install pandas`. Then restart the kernel and try the import statement. It should then work. That is because the magic install commands added in 2019 insure the installation run in the notebook in that manner will be installed in the environment where the kernel backing the ...

Comment: <continued> running `.ipynb` file. See more about the modern magic `%pip install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) meant to be run inside an active running Jupyter `.ipynb` file backed by the ipykernel.

Answer (score 1):

1. `pandas` is not installable via `brew`, so I'm not sure what you've installed there.
2. `pipx` purposefully does not install packages in a way that they can be imported.
3. Depending on the way you've installed Python in the first place, `pip` may not be available globally on your command line, and that's a good thing, since you should be using Python virtualenvs to separate dependencies per project.

Within a Jupyter/IPython session, you should be able to `%pip install pandas` to install Pandas in the same interpreter Jupyter is running on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jupyter, make sure you run it from the virtual environment of the project, not from the system dependencies. I had a similar problem under ubuntu, i.e. the jupyter-notebook command was running jupyter instances from system dependencies, not from the virtual environment.
As a result, jupyter did not see the project dependencies in pipenv/virtualenv.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I had installed Python through the terminal, and because of this, some of its requirements were not installed correctly, and because of this, the pip command was not recognized and Pandas was not added to the pip list. The problem was solved by installing Python through its installation package